# ng-class expression evaluates to false after toggling between tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have working on a code where on certain condition the button should be disabled. My button(Preview value seller) is using data-ng-class where I am passing the expression "disabled:currentQuotation.previewValueSellerDisabled". This evaluates to true when the page loads for the first time, but as soon as I toggle between pages or tabs the button becomes activated. I changed the data-ng-class to data-ng-disabled but it is not working. Not sure if I am missing something.I debugged the response object and it contains the following.

response object :-
message: "OK"
previewdisabled: "true"
responsetime: "615"
status: "1"

When I run once more then the response object is not showing anything. I found that response object is coming from this java code.

```
public DataBean checkQuoteBrandCode(DataBean input) {
            DataBean result =  Helper.getResponseTemplate();
            Long quoteid = Long.valueOf(input.getString("quoteid"));
            List<Ctmtcom> comList = manageConfigurationRepo.getAllComponents(quoteid);


    DataBean component = new DataBean();
                for(Ctmtcom ctmtcom: comList){
                    component.setValue("brandcode", ctmtcom.getBrandcode());
                    if(ctmtcom.getBrandcode().equals("26")){
                        result.setValue("previewdisabled",true);
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                result.setValue("previewdisabled",false);
                return result;
            }
```

My Controller code :-

```
var doLater = function(response){   
    if($scope.currentQuotation.headerData.status == "Value Seller Approved"){
        if(response.previewdisabled=="true"){
            $scope.currentQuotation.previewValueSellerDisabled = true;
            $scope.currentQuotation.acceptValueSellerDisabled = true;
        }else{
            $scope.currentQuotation.previewValueSellerDisabled = false;
            $scope.currentQuotation.acceptValueSellerDisabled = false;
        }
        $scope.previewValueSellerLinkShow = true;
    }else{
        $scope.previewValueSellerLinkShow = false;
    }
```

My HTML

```
<div class="ibm-small" style="float:left;padding-left:35px;padding-top:5px" 
     data-ng-if=" ((appname=='PSAT' && currentQuotation.quoteCustomer.vsmandatory=='Y')  || appname=='PCS' ) && !sp2user && (currentQuote.overViewData.geoCode=='AP' || currentQuotation.overViewData.geoCode=='NA' || (currentQuotation.overViewData.geoCode=='EM' && currentQuotation.detailPricing.useAGOG=='Y' && currentQuotation.detailPricing.vspDeployed=='Y') && currentQuotation.detailPricing.dis=='N')">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="" data-ng-click="previewAddendum()" data-ng-class="{disabled:currentQuotation.previewValueSellerDisabled}">
        <svg class="icon icon-eye"><title>Preview value seller offer</title><use xlink:href="#icon-eye"></use></svg>
        <strong translate="Preview_Value_Seller_Offer"></strong>                
    </button>       
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. <--- look here

Comment: currentQuotation.previewValueSellerDisabled doesn't appear to be in the code sample you provide. **"Minimal, Complete,Verifiable Example"**

Comment: i think it would help if you include the value of response you get.

Comment: @arnoldemzi. This is my response object message: "OK"
previewdisabled: "true"
responsetime: "615"
status: "1"
When I toggle tabs or pages it doesn't show response object.

Answer (score 0):

You stated above that you changes 'ng-class' to 'ng-disabled'

your problem earlier is your using ng-class, remember ng-class will add class if the expression is true. it will not automatically disabled your button (except if your class using css to manually disabled the button).

now the problem is i think your still passing {disabled:currentQuotation.previewValueSellerDisabled} as expression, the problem is clear. The expression itself is wrong, you dont need to pass "disabled" all you need to do is just pass the variable "currentQuotation.previewValueSellerDisabled" looks like this

ng-disabled="currentQuotation.previewValueSellerDisabled"

but remember i'm just guessing what you passed on your data-ng-disabled when you say you change to it

Comment: I have updated my problem and found that response object is not getting populated second time and this response object is coming from java databean file.

Comment: ohh i see, sorry to tell you i cannot help anymore this question not angular anymore have a good day! :)